# Api Platform Modules on Vendor

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm encountering an issue with Symfony autoconfiguration for repositories in my Api Platform module. I'm attempting to modularize my API, and the module for products (https://github.com/ControleOnline/api-platform-products) is not reading the repositories, resulting in the following error:

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!
!!  In FileLoader.php line 174:
!!
!!    Expected to find class "ControleOnline\common\src\Listener\LogListener" in
!!    file "/home/control2/sistemas/controleonline/api/vendor/controleonline/comm
!!    on/src/Listener/LogListener.php" while importing services from resource "..
!!    /vendor/controleonline/*/src/*", but it was not found! Check the namespace
!!    prefix used with the resource in /home/control2/sistemas/controleonline/api
!!    /config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/home/control2/sistemas
!!    /controleonline/api/config/services.yaml").
!!
!!
!!  In FileLoader.php line 224:
!!
!!    Expected to find class "ControleOnline\common\src\Listener\LogListener" in
!!    file "/home/control2/sistemas/controleonline/api/vendor/controleonline/comm
!!    on/src/Listener/LogListener.php" while importing services from resource "..
!!    /vendor/controleonline/*/src/*", but it was not found! Check the namespace
!!    prefix used with the resource.
!!
!!
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

Here's my configuration file: https://github.com/ControleOnline/api-community/tree/master/config

I just need to be able to perform the separation into modules.

**The problem appears to be the namespace** when uses a wildcard

Answer (score 0):

Check that your repository service is correctly defined in your Symfony service configuration. The service definition should include the correct class and be tagged with "doctrine.repository_service." Check the service definition in your module's services.yaml file.

```yaml
services:
    ControleOnline\Repository\ProductRepository:
        class: 'ControleOnline\Repository\ProductRepository'
        tags: ['doctrine.repository_service']
```

Check if your module has its own Doctrine configuration file, and make sure it properly configures the entity manager and repository services.

In your module's config/packages/doctrine.yaml file:

```yaml
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

**Important:**
After making changes to your configuration, clear the Symfony cache :

```bash
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Make sure to clear both the dev and prod environments.

Comment: Thanks for response. The problem is in wildcard (*). Look my service: https://github.com/ControleOnline/api-community/blob/master/config/services.yaml

Comment: **The problem appears to be the namespace** when uses a wildcard